# A discrete random variable question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The probability distribution of the discrete random variable $X$ is
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[X=x] = \begin{cases}
> k/x,    & x \in \{1,2,3\}\\
> m/(2x), & x \in \{6,9\}\\
> 0,      & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> where $k,m$ are positive constants. Given that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 3.8$, find $\mathbb{Var}(X)$.

How does one do this question? I tried but am stuck, could somebody please help?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Well, you have two parameters, $k,m$ you need to solve for.  Can you find two equations involving them?

Comment: Do I need to consider e(X) = sum of xipi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

So your distribution is in terms of two parameters, $k$ and $m$, and you are given $\mathbb{E}[X]$. Let's use it.

1. Find the total weight of the distribution. If you sum over all possible values of $X$, the total weight should be a well-known constant. That will give you one relationship between $k$ and $m$.
2. Find $\mathbb{E}[X]$ from the distribution in terms of $k,m$. This will give you a second relationship between $k$ and $m$.
3. Solve the $2 \times 2$ system to find $k,m$.
4. Compute the variance.

Comment: Thanks I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 unknowns, we need 2 equations to solve. First we might use the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ is a PMF. We can use the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X=x_i) = 1$$
From your question it is obvious that $x_i's$ are $\{1,2,3,6,9\}\ $ for rest of them values are $0$. We get:
$$k+\frac{k}{2}+\frac{k}{3}+\frac{m}{12}+\frac{m}{18}=1$$
$$\frac{11k}{6}+\frac{5m}{36}=1$$
or
$$66k+5m=36$$
For the next part, we know that $$\mathbb{E}(X)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)=3.8$$
$$1\times k+2\times \frac{k}{2}+3\times \frac{k}{3} + 6\times \frac{m}{2\times6}+ 9\times \frac{m}{2\times 9}=3.8$$
$$3k+m=3.8$$
Solving both equations you get, $k=\frac{1}{3},m=\frac{14}{5}$
To calculate the variance, we calculate:
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)=1\times k+4\times \frac{k}{2}+9\times \frac{k}{3}+ 36\times \frac{m}{12}+81\times \frac{m}{18}$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = 6k+7.5m=6\times \frac{1}{3}+ 7.5\times \frac{14}{5}=23$$
$$\mathbb{V}ar(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-[\mathbb{E}(X)]^2=23-(3.8)^2=8.56$$
Hope this helps...